# How do I send a value that starts with a dash to Getopt::Long?

Tags: perl, getopt-long, commandargument

I've got a client-side script I'm making that communicates with GNU-FTP. I want to be able to send it a custom argument on the command line, so I've created an argument `--ftp-args`

This is what it looks like

```
GetOptions(
  .. redacted stuff..
  "ftp-args=s%" => \$FTP_ARGS
) or die("Error in command line arguments\n");
```

However, whenever I try to call it I get an error,

```
$ ./script/dm-ftp360 --ftp-args="-E"
Option ftp-args, key "-E", requires a value
Error in command line arguments
```

Is it possible to get around this, and make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've [specified `s%`](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Options-with-hash-values) - defining an option that specifies hash entries.  That implies a form `key=value` for each argument to the option.  But you've only specified `-E`.  The error message is about the missing `=value` part, not the leading `-`.

Perhaps use `s@` instead to ingest a set of simple options?  Or give an empty value using `"-E="` if you need to separate the keys and values before passing them to ftp.

Comment: I didn't want the '%' at all simple `=s`. Damn, so much for copy-and-pasting code I've used a thousand times without looking it up.

Comment: @EvanCarroll I keep a skeleton script that has all the boilerplate code, including GetOpt::Long, so I don't have to remember.